# What does the west wind signify to New Yorkers?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The New Yorker carries the archives of entertaining old articles. Among them there was a short piece titled “The street and into the grill” written by E.B. White and published in October 1950. A man approaches and take out a reception desk girl from her office:

> “They entered the restaurant. **The wind was still west**, ruffling
>   the edges of the cookies. --When they went down the elevator and out
>   and turned in to the old, hard, beat-up pavement of Fifth Avenue and
>   headed south toward Forty-fifth Street where the pigeons were, the air
>   was as clean as your grandfather’s howitzer. **The wind was still
>   west**.”
>   http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1950/10/14/across-the-street-and-into-the-grill

In Japan, north wind means mid-winter. It should be the north wind that let the travelor fasten down buttons of his overcoat in 'The Sun and the North wind,' while the east wind heralds the arrival of spring season. What does west wind imply to New Yorkers and north-east Americans? Is it still cold mid-winter?

Comment: I think it just means: ***West*** (adj.)
1. To, toward, of, facing, or in the west.
2. Originating in or coming from the west: a gentle west wind.

Comment: Yes, in the US a "west wind" is simply a wind coming from the west.  Given that the coast in that part of the US faces southeast, a west wind would be blowing from inland, and would not be expected to be especially strong or stormy (though I'm no New Yorker and I'm not familiar with any quirks in the weather there).  It's not clear exactly where they were, but 5th Ave runs from south-southwest to north-northeast, so the wind (being blocked by the buildings) would not have been bothering them too badly, except perhaps at intersections.

Comment: Reading the actual story, it appears to contain a lot of nonsense.  White quite often wrote stuff that was, in one way or another, not serious (especially when under the influence of his office mate James Thurber), so you'd best not spend a lot of time trying to understand the story.

Comment: What time of year was it?  In the winter, very cold wind from the arctic will come from the west or northwest (which still registers as west from the Manhattan frame of reference).  In warmer weather, large systems that bring thunderstorms usually approach from the southwest or west.  Whether White had any of this in mind, I have no idea.  @Josh61 have you spent much time in or near New York?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know whether to laugh or cry.  From "Across the Street and into the Grill" (emphasis is mine):

> They left the piano in the restaurant, and when they went down the
>   elevator and out and turned in to the old, hard, beat-up pavement of
>   Fifth Avenue and headed south toward Forty-fifth Street where the
>   pigeons were, **the air was as clean as your grandfather’s howitzer**.
>   The wind was still west.

This is a parody of Ernest Hemingway's style, in particular of Ernest Hemingway's novel *Across the River and into the Trees*.

For those interested in a taste of Hemingway's signature style, click [here](http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/4652599-a-farewell-to-arms).

Comment: Could you provide an example taken from Hemmingway?

Comment: @Mari-LouA You've never read anything by Hemingway?  Consider yourself lucky.  GIYF or go here:  http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/4652599-a-farewell-to-arms

Comment: You should include that link in your answer! I've only read "The old man and the sea" which I liked, but that was years ago.

Comment: Link, done.  As I recall *TOMATS*, Hemingway's last novel,  is somewhat of a departure from his previous writing.

Comment: @deadrat - I don't have a horse in this race, but I would hardly say Hemingway isn't worth reading. The Old Man and the Sea is a national treasure.

Comment: @medica Good thing, since it's not a race; just a matter of taste:  Faulkner is a national treasure; Hemingway is everything EBW shows him to be.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Here are two sentences from the beginning of Hemingway's *Across the River and into the Trees*: "The shooter sat on a shooting stool fastened to the top of a box that contained his lunch and shells, and the shooter's two, or more, guns were propped against the load of wooden decoys." ... "After a while, the shooter, who was working hard and steadily and sweating in his heavy clothes, asked the boatman, 'Where is the shooting barrel?'" I kind of have to agree with you, deadrat, that this is hilariously appalling.

Answer (score 2):

Are these people even in New York? It's a valid question.

Can you take anything in that article as valid? Some sentences:

> - The girl was near enough now so he could smell her fresh receptiveness, and the lint in her hair. Her skin was light blue, like the sides of horses.
> - “But first I must phone Mummy.” She stepped into a public booth and dialled true and well, using her finger. Then she telephoned.
> - “Good morning, my Assistant Treasurer,” said Botticelli, coming forward with a fiasco in each hand.
> - Botticelli led the way to the table in the corner... Botticelli disappeared and returned soon, carrying the old Indian blanket. ...Mr. Pirnie and the girl from the reception desk crawled down under the table and pulled the Indian blanket over them so it was solid and good and covered them right.
> - “Dee the soft-shelled crabs,” said Pirnie from under the blanket. He put his arm around the receptionist good.

None of those things make sense. Maybe New Yorkers think horses are light blue, but I doubt it (I grew up less than 50 miles from NYC, and besides, they have police who patrol on regular, real, non-blue horses.

I never saw the wind ruffle the edges of cookies, west, north, east or other.

It's nonsensical. Most of it means nothing. Which is not to say E.B. White was not a good writer.

Comment: This story reads like a proto-fanfic! Fascinating.

Comment: @Medica. I'm glad to know that this question caught you and Mari Lou's eyes. I don't know who is E.B. White at all, nor why New Yorker mailed the article carried in the magazine 65 yeas ago to me now  as a reading worthy for reminiscence, though I felt the eoisode is entertaining still today and even to a foreign octogenerarian. I thought there was a picture of Hemmingway above this writing. Is he an epigon of Hemmingway?

Comment: @Caleb Bernard. What does 'proto fanfic' mean? I googled for definition in vain.

Comment: @YoichiOishi It's a combination of the word 'fanfic', short for fan fiction, which is a piece of fiction that a fan of a story writes to continue the story. These are usually known for having very poor style. I think it's roughly equivalent to the Japanese term 'doujinshi'. Proto- is a prefix meaning that the thing is an incomplete version of something which came before it. So when I say 'proto-fanfic', I mean that this story by E.B. White, while it came before the concept of fan fiction, bears resemblance to fan fiction.

Answer (score 2):

*The west wind* doesn't signify anything to New Yorkers other than the literal direction the wind is coming from.

But that's not nearly the whole story with this passage. As others have noted, *Across the Street and into the Grill* was written as a parody of [Ernest Hemingway's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Hemingway) writing style, complete with run-on sentences, strange repetition, and use of words in nonsensical contexts. The website has subtly(?) indicated this: the picture on the page is of Hemingway.

And even *that* isn't the whole story, because the author is [E.B. White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._B._White). E.B. White wrote *Charlotte's Web* and *Stuart Little*, both of which are much-loved books for children. In addition, he's the "White" in "Strunk & White": he's one of the authors of the very famous (or infamous) English writing style guide *The Elements of Style*.

Bottom line is, The New Yorker believed it was worth revisiting this "classic" not because of how well it's written (though *as a parody*, it is indeed well-written), but because of who wrote it and why.

Answer (score 1):

We use the term "the west wind blows" when things are not right and danger is afoot.  Being of Irish descent, I have many personal remembrances of the term being used by relatives.  It is a commonly used phrase in Irish poetry and ballads (Dollard, 1910) reflecting the increased risks of fisherman and sailors who go out to sea when the west wind blows. The Wizard of Oz focuses on the wicked witch of the west who appears initially as a result of a tornado.  At work, we use the term to mean that the boss is not in a good mood and the chances of an unpleasant event occurring is heightened. This may just be a turn of phrase to reflect and ill-wind and things not being "right"?